# Changing the view of a div created by loop without re-running the loop in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

How can I change the view of a `<div>` created by a loop which observes a change in its attribute,  without changing the view of other `<div>` created by the loop.

I am looping an array variable to display a set of list in each div .

```
{{#each val in property1}}

    <div class="grid1">
       {{val.value}}
     </div>
{{/each}}
```

Suppose my **property1** looks like this

```
  property1:function(){
   array1 = [{
      value:'person1',
      address:'place1' 
  },
   {
      value:'person2',
      address:'place2' 
  }] 
 return array1;
}.property('flagValue')
```

Now the on changing the **flagValue** , **property1** is called again and the DOM also gets updated. HOW CAN I OBSERVE THE **address**  of a particular index in **array1** object and change the view of the  associated to that index without re-running the whole loop again.

Comment: I dont think you need to handle any kind of rerendering ur self. Ember does its own value diffing and only updates the relevant DOM nodes.

Comment: If you use Ember.Object instances instead of pure JS objects you can do a .set on the object and this should not re-run the loop.